# How to connect a microsoft webchat bot with salesforce live agent?

Tags: salesforce, botframework, integration

I developed a webchat bot using bot framework Node.js. How can I integrate this bot with the salesforce live agent?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your question and help us to help you please have a look at
the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
It's also always a good  choice to add an [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello, are you asking how to do a bot-to-human handoff? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human

Comment: Please let us know which version of the BotBuilder SDK you're using

Comment: Are you still working on this?